# How to open JFileChooser from menu item actionPerformed?

Tags: java, swing, menuitem, jfilechooser

Like in title how to make happen that when I click on menu item should open `JFileChooser` to select *.txt file?

I'm trying this `ActionListener` but don't know how to use is to make it work: could you give me some lead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `ActionListener` to the `JMenuItem`.  In the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` method, open the `JFileChooser`.

When making the `JFileChooser`, cause it to filter for txt files by creating an appropriate `FileNameExtensionFilter` and calling `JFileChooser.setFileFilter(FileFilter)` using that filter.